# Fibonacci in C works great with 1 - 18 but 19 does nothing at all

Tags: c, fibonacci

I have to program a little program that show a Fibonacci sequence from 1 to n.
1 to 18 works great. But from 19 the program does nothing at all and just exit as it's done.
I can not find the error... so please give me an hint.

```
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  pid_t pid;
  int fib[argc];
  int i, size;
  size = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 0L);
  fib[0] = 0;
  fib[1] = 1;
  pid = fork();
  printf("size = %d \n", size);
  if(pid == 0){
    for(i = 2; i < size; i++){
      fib[i] = fib[i-1] + fib[i-2];
    }
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
      printf("\n\t %d ", fib[i]);
    }
  }
  else if(pid > 0){ // Parent, because pid > 0
    wait(NULL);
    printf("\n");
    exit(1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why the heck are you using `fork` to calculate the fibonacci sequence?

Comment: That code doesn't even compile. Can you give the code of the version you are trying to input 19 with?

Comment: I'm using fork cause it's an assignment ;)

Comment: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/216531/
That code compiles and works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues are:

1. <strike>`fib[0]` should be `1`, not `0`</strike>.
2. Size of `fib` array is wrong.
3. And array `fib` is defined wrong too.
4. Seems that `for` fill random membery, not `fib` array elements.

Comment: Can you add "there is no validation of the command line arguments".

Answer (score 0):

Still this code doesn't look very good. You haven't posted includes and for-loop is incomplete. It doesn't even contain code that will actually compute the sequence values.

Next problem is the purpose of forking here. What you want to do is to perform simple sequential calculation. There is no need for fork at all.

I recommend a bit more work on this before submitting this for grade.

Comment: I know that I don't need forking here... But it's an assignment. It's not my fault ;)