# Fibonacci Numbers in c

Tags: c, math, fibonacci

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

/* number of max three digits (max digits = MAX3DIGITS*3) */
#define MAX3DIGITS 100000

/* struct that holds three digits (like 503) */
struct three {
    unsigned n : 10;
};

/* a whole number made up of struct threes */
struct num {
    struct three n[MAX3DIGITS];
} number[2];
FILE *dg;

int main() {


    int naim;
    dg=fopen("deneme.txt","w");



    for(naim=1;naim<1001;naim++){
    int prev = 0;  
    int x, y, n = 0;  
    int digits = 2;  



    number[0].n[0].n = 0;
    number[1].n[0].n = 1;

    while(!kbhit() && ++n < naim && digits <= MAX3DIGITS) {
        //fprintf(stderr, "\r%i", n);

        prev = !prev;

        for(x = 0; x < digits; x ++) {
            y = number[!prev].n[x].n + number[prev].n[x].n;
            number[!prev].n[x].n = (y%1000);
            number[!prev].n[x+1].n += (y/1000);
        }
        if(number[!prev].n[digits-1].n) digits ++;
    }

    fprintf(dg,"\nfib(%i) = %i", n, number[!prev].n[digits-2].n);
    for(x = digits-3; x >= 0; x --) {
        fprintf(dg,"%03i", number[!prev].n[x].n);
    }
    fprintf(dg,"\n");


    }
    printf("sad");
    if(kbhit()) getche();
    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

This code is writing first 1000 Fibonacci numbers. But my problem is starting 18th number. Until seventeenth number , this code is working. But 18th number is wrong so remaining is wrong. How can I fix it ?

Thank You.

Comment: Seems relevant that you have some strange div/mod 1000 code and F17 is the first Fibonacci number over 1000...

Comment: Related: [Fibonacci in C works great with 1 - 18 but 19 does nothing at all](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880306/fibonacci-in-c-works-great-with-1-18-but-19-does-nothing-at-all)

Comment: But If I want to write in the console , this code is working .

Comment: Where is the code initializing all elements to 0?

Comment: Hi Eric, I did it as you say, But It still isnt working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of issuing considerations on the code, I'll just answer the question.
The problem is that you have to initialize (to zero) the memory you're using to store the two numbers. Following a working version of your code, my two small modifications sandwiched between // ***** comments.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
// *****
#include <mem.h>
// *****

/* number of max three digits (max digits = MAX3DIGITS*3) */
#define MAX3DIGITS 100000


/* struct that holds three digits (like 503) */
struct three {
    unsigned n : 10;
};

/* a whole number made up of struct threes */
struct num {
    struct three n[MAX3DIGITS];
} number[2];
FILE *dg;

int main() {


    int naim;
    dg=fopen("deneme.txt","w");


    for(naim=1;naim<1001;naim++){
    int prev = 0;
    int x, y, n = 0;
    int digits = 2;

    // *****
    memset(number, 0, sizeof(number));
    // *****

    number[0].n[0].n = 0;
    number[1].n[0].n = 1;

    while(!kbhit() && ++n < naim && digits <= MAX3DIGITS) {
        //fprintf(stderr, "\r%i", n);

        prev = !prev;

        for(x = 0; x < digits; x ++) {
            y = number[!prev].n[x].n + number[prev].n[x].n;
            number[!prev].n[x].n = (y%1000);
            number[!prev].n[x+1].n += (y/1000);
        }
        if(number[!prev].n[digits-1].n) digits ++;
    }

    fprintf(dg,"\nfib(%i) = %i", n, number[!prev].n[digits-2].n);
    for(x = digits-3; x >= 0; x --) {
        fprintf(dg,"%03i", number[!prev].n[x].n);
    }
    fprintf(dg,"\n");


    }
    printf("sad");
    if(kbhit()) getche();
    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```